# Android Job Scheduler: Perform the job whenever data network is there

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I'm scheduling a job using job Scheduler Service. Condition for my job to be start is availability of  any `network(setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY))`. 
First time, i'm scheduling a job from user input (say:Clicking a button), so when user click the button, once network is available, my job will be started.

My question is, my job should be start without user input for the subsequent time. Is this possible? If yes, please suggest.

(I do not want listen for network change listener. Since it has some limitation from Android N onwards)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible with JobInfo.Builder have a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setMinimumLatency(long)

and can be used in combination with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setRequiredNetworkType(int)

Comment: As per my understanding, setPeriodic will perform of the job after specific time and not as soon as when the network is available. I need to perform my task as soon as network is available

Comment: What about combining it with setMinimumLatency(long minLatencyMillis)? That is the minumum time that has to be passed before executing the task. I guess as long there is no network it will not be executed. Once network is back and the minum time has been passed it will execute it? And then in jobFinished reschedule it?

Comment: any updates for update a specific task when the network is available!...

Answer (score 0):

yes you can set in builder

> setBackoffCriteria

whenever the scheduled job stopped because the constraints doesn't met it will keep trying.

```
    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
    builder.setPeriodic(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
    builder.setBackoffCriteria(1000, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_EXPONENTIAL);
```